# add a custom value to end of each menu item with jquery

Tags: jquery, each, attr

I use jquery to get link of page and add it to cats menu items.
but it has a problem
i want to do this
for example we have this menu

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="link1">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the page address is `example.com/index.php?se1`
now i use jquery to get the value `se1`

```
var pageurl = $(location).attr('href');
var regionurl = pageurl.substr(pageurl.indexOf("?") + 1);
```

and it returns `se1` correctly
but now i want to add se1 to all href values of links inside my list i try this way but its not work correctly

```
$(".nav li a").each(function() {
    var catlink = $(".nav li a").attr('href');
    var fullregionurl = catlink + "?" + regionurl;
    $(".nav li a").attr("href",fullregionurl);
});
```

I want to change links value like this

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="link1?se1">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2?se1">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3?se1">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

help me to solve this
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(this).attr('href')` instead of `$(".nav li a").attr('href')`.

Or you can use `attr()` method like following.

```
var pageurl = $(location).attr('href');
var regionurl = pageurl.substr(pageurl.indexOf("?") + 1);

$(".nav li a").attr('href', function () {
    return $(this).attr('href') + '?' + regionurl;
});
```